# How to Import a CSV and read a line from text file using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have following output from some PowerShell Cmdlet, as below

```
  0    server-1 Content  Damaged       client 12/06/2013 08:00:41
123    server-1 Content  Damaged       client 12/07/2013 08:00:33
  0    server-1 Content  Damaged       client 12/08/2013 08:00:32
234    server-1 Content  Damaged       client 12/09/2013 08:00:34
  0    server-1 Content  Damaged       client 12/09/2013 16:09:41
 70    server-1 Content  Damaged       client 12/10/2013 08:00:33
  0    server-1 Content  Damaged       client 12/11/2013 08:00:31
```

I'm able to append the above output into a text file.

When im trying to Import above ouput in a new CSV file(using `Import-Csv`), all infomation coming under a single cell in a each line,but i need 7 cells in each line !!! please somebody guide me here.

And also please tell me, How to cound a line which is starting from **`0`** using PowerShell ?

Answer (score 2):

`Import-CSV` by default assumes that each record (or row) of data is separated by a comma (hence the name **comma** separated values). If you have something else which is used consistently as your delimiter between fields (such as tab or space), you can use the `-Delimiter` parameter for the cmdlet to specify that and get it to parse properly.

However, `Import-CSV` also assumes that you have a header record, which you do not. So you'll need to either parse your data using `Get-Content` instead, or add a header record (preferable).

Once you're parsing your data into a collection of objects (or really, a collection of collections), just look at the first value in each and see if it equals 0.

Answer (score 2):

The data is not in CSV format, so Import-CSV will not work.  You need to split each line into separate values and create PS Objects using those values.  Each value needs to be assigned to a property of the object, so you'll also need to assign a property name to each one.

There are many ways to accomplish this in Powershell.  Here is one.  The property names are just Prop1-Prop7.  You'll need to replace those with something meaningful, and replace the testfile.txt file name with your file spec.

```
#Create an array of property names
$Props = &{$args} Prop1 Prop2 Prop3 Prop4 Prop5 Prop6 Prop7

Get-Content testfile.txt |
 ForEach-Object {
    $Parts = $_ -split '\s+'  #Split the line at the spaces to create an array of values
    $PropHash = [ordered]@{}  #Create an empty hash table for the property hash (the [ordered] is optional, but keeps the properties in the same order as the property list)
    for ($i=0; $i -le 6; $i++) 
     {$PropHash[$Props[$i]] = $Parts[$i]} #Assign the split values to the property names by their respective array indexes
    [PSCustomObject]$PropHash #Output a PSCustomObject built from the hash table
 }
```